# I am a five digit number, what number am I?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I am a five digit number.
>   Do not worry, seeing me upside down is still me.
>   Rearrange me, the new number is zero.
>   Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, you will be very very sick
>   Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, it is the beast
>   Take 4 digits from me then rearrange them, add the rearranged number with the unused digit, the  result is 10000.
>   My middle is a separator of 2 same numbers, lets call the same number jack.
>   Do not worry, seeing jack upside down is still jack.
>   Jack is 2 digit number, glue it, it is a bicycle part.

What number am I ?

> Do not forget to think literally

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking help from Keyur PATEL's answer, I think the answer is :

I am a five digit number.

> 69169

Do not worry, seeing me upside down is still me.

> 69169 reads the same upside down

Rearrange me, the new number is zero.

> 69 - 69 = 0

Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, you will be very very sick

> Emergency number '999'

Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, it is the beast

> Devil's number '666'

Take 4 digits from me then rearrange them, add the rearranged number with the unused digit, the result is 10000.

> 6969 can be rearranged to form 9999.
>  9999 + 1 = 10000

My middle is a sparator of 2 same numbers, lets call the same number jack.

> The two same number is 69.

Do not worry, seeing jack upside down is still jack.

> 69 upside down is still 69.

Jack is 2 digit number, glue it, it is a bicycle part.

> 69 can be rearranged to form either a single wheel of a bicycle or both the wheels as shown in the image :
>  [image]
>  Edit : It can also form a bicycle gear as :
>  [image]

Comment: Damn! one little misplace!!

Comment: @rvd Check your first picture, if you glue 69  it will create a bicycle gear.

Comment: Yes, missed that.

Comment: Nicely done, I almost had it, but you brought it home :)

Comment: There are only two 9's and two 6's.

Comment: @Devsman "rearrange" includes rotating

Comment: @DavidStarkey Ooooooooooooooooh.

Answer (score 3):

It is a stretch, but here goes:
Are you

> 60109?

Do not worry, seeing me upside down is still me.

> Upside down, it reads 60109 also.

Rearrange me, the new number is zero. (credits: BlueFire)

> Rearranging 60109 could make it so that it becomes 60 - 60, the minus being the 1 and the other 60 being the upside-down 90. Result is 0.

Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, you will be very very sick

> Take '6' reverse it to get '9', take 0 and 1 put them next to each other to get another '9'. Result is '999' the emergency number.

Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, it is the beast

> Similar to the previous one, take '9' reverse it to get '6', put '1' and '0' together to get '6' and you get '666' the devils number.

Take 4 digits from me then rearrange them, add the rearranged number with the unused digit, the result is 10000.

> Not sure about this one, could be using imagery (separating the '6' into '1' and '0', and the same for '9' gives 0000 and "add" the '1' to get "10000")

My middle is a sparator of 2 same numbers, lets call it jack.

> Jack could be '010'

Do not worry, seeing jack upside down is still jack.

> 010 upside down is 010

Jack is 2 digit number, glue it, it is a bicycle part.

> 010, which is 2 digits ('10') added together could resemble a bicycle wheel and chain.

I know its far-fetched, but its a theory.

Comment: Rot-13: erneenatvat 60109 pbhyq znxr vg fb gung vg orpbzrf 60 - 60, gur zvahf orvat gur 1 naq gur bgure 60 orvat gur hcfvqr-qbja 9.

Comment: also don't worry if its bit of a stretch, lateral-thinking answer usually are quite a stretch

Comment: I upvote, but still wrong, try again.

Comment: Thanks @BlueFire, darn answer is not correct though. Re-thinking the overall strategy.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> 96169

Do not worry, seeing me upside down is still me.

> 96169 upside down is 96169

Rearrange me, the new number is zero.

> take 96, rotate 1 to - and flip 69 -> so 96 - 96 = 0

Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, you will be very very sick

> take 996, flip 6 to get 9 -> 999 is emergency number

Take 3 digits from me then rearrange them, it is the beast

> take 6,6,9 flip 9 -> 666 is number of beast(I read 616 is variant, it is also possible)

Take 4 digits from me then rearrange them, add the rearranged number with the unused digit, the result is 10000.

> Take 9669 flip two 6 -> 9999 + 1 = 10000

My middle is a separator of 2 same numbers,

> middle number is 1 separator of two same numbers i.e. 6

lets call the same number jack.
Do not worry, seeing jack upside down is still jack.
Jack is 2 digit number, glue it, it is a bicycle part.

> Here where I am stuck

Comment: I think you'd better do a handstand and check that first bit :) - so close though

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> 69696

Reasoning:

> Number of the beast is 666, if it needs to read the same reversed (9's) then your done right there.

Comment: But upside down doesn't mean reversed, and a lot of the other conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: :sigh: That's right.  Post in haste, repent in leisure.

Comment: You're on the right track nevertheless, I'm going down a similar path as well.

Comment: Be creative, this is a **lateral thinking** problem